# Call a protected base class function from nested struct

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

Normally nested structures have access to the owning classes `public`, `protected` and `public` member functions. There is also no problems calling a `protected` member function of a base class from within the nested structure, i.e. the following code compiles and works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {}

protected:
    void baseProtectedFunc()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "Called for Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    explicit Derived() : Base()
    {}

    void accessBaseProtectedFuncFromNested()
    {
        Nested myNested( this );
        myNested();
    }

private:
    struct Nested
    {
        explicit Nested( Derived* ptr ) : derived_( ptr ) 
        {}

        void operator()()
        {
            derived_->baseProtectedFunc();
        }

        Derived* derived_;
    };
};

int main( int, char** )
{
    Derived myDerived;
    myDerived.accessBaseProtectedFuncFromNested();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, consider the following code that uses `mpl::inherit_linearly` to generate the base classes for derived, using an `mpl::vector` of types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit_linearly.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {}

protected:
    void baseProtectedFunc()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "Called for Base< " << typeid(T).name() << " >\n";
    }
};

typedef boost::mpl::vector< long
    , unsigned
    , bool
    , std::string
    > parameter_type_list_t;

typedef boost::mpl::inherit_linearly< parameter_type_list_t
                  , boost::mpl::inherit< boost::mpl::_1
                                       , Base< boost::mpl::_2 > > 
                  >::type base_types;

class Derived : public base_types
{
public:
    explicit Derived() : base_types()
    {}

    template<typename T>
    void accessBaseProtectedFuncFromNested()
    {
        Nested myNested( this );

        myNested.someFunc<T>();
    }

private:
    struct Nested
    {
        explicit Nested( Derived* ptr ) : derived_( ptr ) 
        {}

        template< typename T >
        void someFunc()
        {
            Base<T>* base = static_cast<Base<T>*>( derived_ );
            base->baseProtectedFunc();
        }

        Derived* derived_;
    };
};

int main( int, char** )
{
    Derived myDerived;
    myDerived.accessBaseProtectedFuncFromNested<unsigned>();

    return 0;
}
```

Using GCC version 4.4.6-3 (in c++03 and c++0x mode) the following error is generated:

```
friend-prot.cpp: In member function ‘void Derived::Nested::someFunc() [with T = unsigned int]’:
friend-prot.cpp:47:   instantiated from ‘void Derived::accessBaseProtectedFuncFromNested() [with T = unsigned int]’
friend-prot.cpp:82:   instantiated from here
friend-prot.cpp:17: error: ‘void Base<T>::baseProtectedFunc() [with T = unsigned int]’ is protected
friend-prot.cpp:72: error: within this context
```

If I make the function I am trying to call `public` the code compiles and works as expected.

I can get around the issue by adding an additional `private` member function to derived that simply forwards the call from Nested, i.e.:

```
struct Nested
{
    explicit Nested( Derived* ptr ) : derived_( ptr ) 
    {}

    template< typename T >
    void operator()()
    {
        derived_->forwarder<T>();
    }

    Derived* derived_;
}; 


template< typename T >
void forwarder()
{
    Base<T>::baseProtectedFunc();
}
```

I do not understand why I cannot call `baseProtectedFunc()` if it is `protected` when `mpl::inherit` is used.

Why am I allowed to call a base class protected function in the first example and not in the second?

Comment: It may be related to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933999/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-private-method-in-a-lambda . It seems like a gcc bug.

Comment: @JurajBlaho thanks for that input, I was suspecting a compiler bug but do not have anything else to try the code on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that you would get the same error if you wrote the forwarding function as

```
template <typename T>
void forwarder()
{
    Base<T>* base = static_cast<Base<T>*>( derived_ );
    base->baseProtectedFunc();
}
```

The problem is that the cast to a base pointer obscures to the compiler the fact that `baseProtectedFunc` is actually accessible from the current context with the specified pointer. As this is obscured, the compiler has to assume the access is not allowed through that pointer.

As the syntax you used in the forwarding function can also be used from within the nested class, the solution is rather simple and elegant:

```
struct Nested
{
    explicit Nested( Derived* ptr ) : derived_( ptr ) 
    {}

    template< typename T >
    void someFunc()
    {
        derived_->Base<T>::baseProtectedFunc(); /* <-- Changed */
    }

    Derived* derived_;
};
```