# Calling private destructor as deleter for std::shared_ptr using lambda?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, lambda, anonymous-function

For this game, I have a Game class, it's a singleton... Here's the header file

```
#ifndef SOKOBAN_GAME_H
#define SOKOBAN_GAME_H
#include <memory>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
namespace sokoban
{
  class Game
  {
  public:
    static Game* getInstance();
    void startGame();
  private:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    Game(const Game&) = delete;
    Game(Game&&) = delete;
    Game& operator=(const Game&) = delete;
    Game& operator=(Game&&) = delete;

    static std::shared_ptr<Game> instance_;
    SDL_Surface* mainSurface_;
  };
};
#endif
```

Now, most of the implementation file is unimportant except for the getInstance function:

```
Game* Game::getInstance()
{
  if(!Game::instance_)
  {
    Game::instance_ = std::shared_ptr<Game>(new Game,
    [](Game* ptr)
    {
      delete ptr;
    });
  }

  return Game::instance_.get();
}
```

As you can see, my lazy-initialize style requires that I use a smart pointer, however because I am trying to avoid a public destructor, I have to use a lambda as a deleter, now this code compiles fine, however I can't seem to find any pattern of why a lambda, said by the standard to be a separate unique object, can call this private method, especially after looking at some questions on SO like:

- [Why is it not possible to use private method in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933999/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-private-method-in-a-lambda)

What I basically want to know is the access rules of a lambda in a member function like the example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says in 5.1.2/3

> The type of the lambda-expression [...] is a unique [...] class type —
>   called the closure type [...] The closure type is declared in the
>   smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains
>   the corresponding lambda-expression.

This means that a lambda that occurs inside a (member) function is treated like a local class, declared at block scope in the surrounding function. About local classes, the standard says in 9.8/1:

> [...] The local class is in the scope of the enclosing scope, and has
>   the same access to names outside the function as does the enclosing
>   function.[...]

Thus the lambda has the same access as the containing member function, which means that it can access private members of the class.

If a lambda occurs directly in a class scope, it would be treated as a nested class, for which a similar rule applies: 11.7/1 says:

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as
>   any other member.

Either way, a lambda that occurs within in the scope of a class has access to private class members. So your example is fine.

(The post you referred to, ultimately was about a problem accessing protected members of base classes named by a *qualified-id*.)