# Accessing private member function via Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, function-pointers

In a project, I have a C-API which uses C-style function pointers as callbacks. In one of those callbacks, I need to access a private function of an object `Foo`. Note that the API-call is done within a function of my class. Because of not shown code, I have a handle to my object as a `void*` accessible to me.

Things aside that the construct is prone to errors, by passing a lambda as callback I am able to access the private function of my object.
This is somewhat unexpected but welcome to me. I haven't found anything regarding this behavior, so I would kindly ask if somebody could shed some light why this is actual working. I am not aware that the lambda is catching something, but it appears that is has something to do with the actual scoping.
I am using C++17 and gcc 10.2.

Here's a sample block of code:

```cpp
void TestFunc(void (*)(void*)) {
}

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
     TestFunc([](void* handle){
         auto foo = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(handle);
         foo->BarFunc();
     });
    };
private:
    void BarFunc() {};
};
```

Comment: My first instinct is that *code is code* so if you *can* get something to point to the private function, then anything could run it. Void pointers are basic units of memory, so I'd imagine you're essentially stripping the private func of its anonymity and typechecking and just letting anyone use it.

Comment: That being said, clever C hacks like this usually mean that something has gone horribly, terribly wrong, and and you should probably refactor your code or risk madness

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why is it not possible to use private method in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933999/)

Comment: Interesting here is that it won’t work outside the class definition. Appears that this is because of the standard ixSci wrote. To be fair, I was not happy with it, so this was purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working because Standard allows it. So first we have this (C++20 [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2)):

> The closure type is declared in the smallest **block scope**, class scope,
> or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.
> <...>

And in your example we have a block scope so in the end we have an unnamed local class declaration and according to [[class.local]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.local#1):

> A class can be declared within a function definition; such a class is
> called a local class. The name of a local class is local to its
> enclosing scope. The local class is in the scope of the enclosing
> scope, and **has the same access to names outside the function as does
> the enclosing function**